My dog drank dirty soap water. (Dish detergent)
My dog (caramel) drank dirty soap water that would leak into a pot under our sink due to a leaking pipe until we get it fixed (in the process of that). I’m not entirely too sure how much she drank since my whole family was asleep. When I found out that she did it, I noticed she had her tail between her legs and was walking as if she was weak and tired. She hasn’t eat anything and all she does is sleep. I been giving her water by put small amounts into her mouth as she would drink it. Her heart beat feels fine and her temperature seems to be normal. She has pooped once since it happened and it was liquidated poop. No signs of bleeding or vomit. I can’t afford to go the vet and I’m extremely worried. Can someone help me??

At this moment there's not much you can do. Causing her to vomit won't expell the dish water anymore, because it already passed her stomach.
You should call your local pet poison hotline and ask for specific advice for your specific dish soap. There are so many different products that it's impossible to give general advice.
Read the label of your dish soap and see if there's any essential oils in there. They usually appear at the end of the list and may be written in latin, so you may have to google every ingredient in there. Many essential oils that are safe for humans are toxic for dogs. Also look for a note to contact poison control in case of swallowing. If you find such a note or any essential oils in the ingredients, a vet visit may be unavoidable.
If you have charcoal pills (medical grade activated charcoal) you can try giving her one. If she doesn't swallow the pill, dissolve it in some instant broth or the juices of a can of wet dog food. It's a home remedy that's supposed to bind toxins and let them pass the body without being absorbed. I don't know how much good it will do, but at least it doesn't have any side effects but making her poop black.
In the mean time, make sure she has easy access to clean water. Severe diarrhea can quickly cause dehydration. Also switch to a bland diet for the next few days. Dry kibble soaked in water or if she refuses that, instant potato mash (pure potato flakes without any salt or other spices like onion or garlic powder) prepared only with hot water and no milk or fat. Use more water than instructed to make it thin enough to be licked up easily.
She may be unable to control her bowel movement, so better confine her to some place you can clean easily.
